# Swift ios touch id login flow

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, touch-id

In my app a user can authenticate/login to my backend using email/password. Now I am thinking of implementing touch ID as well.

But I am confused about the login flow using a touch ID.

Using the code bellow I can easy authenticate a user:

```
func authenticateUser() {
    let context = LAContext()
    var error: NSError?

    if context.canEvaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, error: &error) {
        let reason = "Identify yourself!"

        context.evaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, localizedReason: reason) {
            [unowned self] success, authenticationError in

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if success {
                    self.runSecretCode()
                } else {
                    let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Authentication failed", message: "Sorry!", preferredStyle: .alert)
                    ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
                    self.present(ac, animated: true)
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Touch ID not available", message: "Your device is not configured for Touch ID.", preferredStyle: .alert)
        ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
        present(ac, animated: true)
    }
}
```

But I dont know which user it is.

So, when a user creates an account, should I store something like the device ID(if that exists) in my DB then when the users uses touch ID I can check what device ID it is then log the user in?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, touch ID only acts as a gatekeeper to the native app iteself, not the API.

No matter what, your user would have to authenticate with the API at least once to get some kind of secret token(JWT, etc) which would then be persisted through closing/opening of the app. Touch ID would have to be successful before your app would start making calls to the API, but the API will only validate against the secret.

This way you can persist the user's login without saving credentials, and you have touch ID on the app to keep an unwanted user from picking up an unlocked phone and just opening the banking app.

This is how I understand it, but if I'm wrong, someone please correct me.